# NetModel fails to load a pre-trained model

Tags: neural-networks

Running *Mathematica 11.1.1* on windows

```
NetModel["LeNet Trained on MNIST Data"]
```

as per the help page gives `$Failed` result.

Internet connectivity test passes. Wolfram account signed into.

Not sure if it ran once or not and I have a cached data problem, but search for .wlnet files yields nothing.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The Documentation Center example code works fine for me. I evaluated `net = NetModel["LeNet Trained on MNIST Data"]` on system (V11.1.1 running on OS X 1010.2) successfully. The model took about 15 seconds to load.

Comment: may you don't sign in wolfram account

Answer (score 1):

Enabling 'automatically check for data updates' in preferences-internet_connectivity did the trick