# Unable to retrieve NetModel in 11.2

Tags: neural-networks

In v11.1, I can retrieve a trained model with

```
net = NetModel["LeNet Trained on MNIST Data"]
```

However, in v11.2, this returns with a `$Failed` message. I made sure I was logged in, had internet connectivity, cleared the cache in `%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Roaming\Wolfram\Objects\Resources`, and enabled automatic update as per [NetModel fails to load a pre-trained model](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/149372/netmodel-fails-to-load-a-pre-trained-model), but the error persists. Retrieving other models gives the same result. Is this reproducible for other people?

Comment: Fails for me as well in 11.2 on Windows. I'd report it to Wolfram.

Comment: @user6014 Just did. I'll update this question once I get a reply