# NetModel fails to load a pre-trained model: Very Deep Net for Super-Resolution, in 11.3

Tags: neural-networks

I'm trying to run VDSR in Mathematica 11.3 on windows.

My situation is:

in:

```
NetModel["Very Deep Net for Super-Resolution"]
```

out:

```
$Failed
```

Internet connectivity test passes. Wolfram account signed into.

I already check this question:

[NetModel fails to load a pre-trained model](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/149372/netmodel-fails-to-load-a-pre-trained-model)

```
NetModel["LeNet Trained on MNIST Data"]
```

↑ This model runs properly so Internet connection and Wolfram account are working.

Please tell me any suggestions. I think there's something wrong related to Windows Defender.

Comment: It works for me (11.3 on Windows 7).

Comment: Can you try `ResourceRemove@ResourceObject["Very Deep Net for Super-Resolution"]`, then run `Quit` and try again?